# RestKit can't save dates that are formatted as strings in JSON-request to my local database

Tags: objective-c, ios, restkit

I'm using RestKit to sync JSON to a local database, and I'm having some problems with saving dates, I keep getting `Category is not key value coding-compliant for the key "createdAt".` The JSON I get from the remote web-service is a string and looks like this:

```
"created_at":"2012-06-20T13:29:54Z"
```

In my local `xdatamodeld` file I have tried to have `created_at` attribute where I have tried both NSSTring and NSdate as data types. I have a local model file for the entity with the created_at @property: `@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate *createdAt;`. I have tried both NSString and NSDate here as well. I have also tried to create a date formatter for the `RKManagedObjectMapping`, but it didn't help either. Like this:

```
NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
[dateFormatter  setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];

categoryMapping.dateFormatters = [NSArray arrayWithObject: dateFormatter];
```

My mapping looks like this:

```
[categoryMapping mapKeyPath:@"categories.created_at" toAttribute:@"createdAt"];
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

** UPDATE **

I suspect that the Z is causing the error. How could I strip that away from the request before mapping it?

** UPDATE #2 **

I have now also tried to add a new addDefaultDateFormatter, but that didn't work wither. Like this (before I create my own mappings):

```
// JSON date format: 2012-06-20T13:29:54Z 
NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init]; 
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"]; 

[RKObjectMapping addDefaultDateFormatterForString:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ" inTimeZone:nil];
[RKObjectMapping addDefaultDateFormatter:dateFormatter];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things.

1) The error you report is nothing to do with date formatting, it simply says that this entity does not have an property/attribute named createdAt. Check your map is mapping to the correct object and your object in fact has the correct property.

2) Your date formatter is wrong. It should have the format:

```
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'
```

But this is already one of the default date formatters for RestKit, so you should not need to specify it. This is ISO8601 format by the way (ie: standard date).

Comment: Thanks, you were right, it was my mapping and data model that was wrong.